# Flot Chart Bar Width Issue

Tags: php, jquery, json, flot

One a page using database I am rendering multiple Bar Charts using Flot charts of Flat-kit Theme. For a specific data set it gives me overlapped x-axis grid lines plus my bars are not rendered properly.

Kindly see the image where at top of each graph data and ticks are also echoed by me to help you find if there is any error with data or ticks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you see the right chart in your image as improperly rendered. But in fact it is rendered correctly for the data you have given. Your x values and therefore also the x axis range from about 3060 to 3240 so each bar is pretty narrow.

If you want the bars to be at equal distance and the same width as in the left chart you have to use [category mode](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/categories/index.html) (which basically means using x values from 1 to 10 as in the left chart).

Comment: Thanks for much needed help

Comment: @Shakeel If the answer did help you, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the checkmark to the left.